# Loop through 2 dates and execute a condition each 12 days, 2 days, 12 days, 2 days, etc

Tags: php, algorithm, datetime

I want to execute a condition during a loop between 2 dates.

This is my code :

```
 for($i = $periodStartAt; $periodStartAt <= $endAt; $i->modify('+1 day')){

   // when it's 12 days

   // when it's 2 days (after the 12 days)

   // when it's 12 days (after the 2 days)

   // etc.....

   }
```

Anyone can help with this algorithm ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider a *period* to be 14 days long, which could be split in two *subperiods* - first of 12 days and the second of 2 days.

So each step of your loop could process 14 days:

```
$periodStartAt = 0;
while(true) {
    $periodStartAt += 12; // first sub-period
    if ($periodStartAt > $endAt) break;
    //do something when first sub-period reached

    $periodStartAt += 2; //second sub-period 
    if ($periodStartAt > $endAt) break;
    //do something when second sub-period reached
}
```

Comment: Thanks i splitted into 14 days periods.